# EGit: what problems will I run into because there's no Recursive Merge available?

Tags: dvcs, egit

I've been looking into using EGit for Eclipse. Apparently it's based on JGit which is not a complete implementation of git - so no recursive merge functionality.

If I'm understanding the ramifications, this means that there will be issues with criss-cross merges and with file renaming.

But what will those issues look like? / How painful are the work-arounds?

Answer (score 0):

The recursive merge strategy is the default since EGit 3.0 (see [bug 380314](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=380314)).